# limiting input field to numbers only

Tags: javascript, html

Im writing a program for school and he wants us to do the following : If any non-numeric entry is made in the Age field, an alert box should appear with the two line message:

The age that you entered must contain only numerals.
Please re-enter it.

Then : If the age entered is less than 18, then an additional paragraph should appear below the button containing the message

And Then : For ages 18 and over, the script must calculate and display a salary offer based on the applicant's attainment of a college degree. If the applicant holds a degree, then the salary offer will be determined by multiplying the applicant's age times $1000.00. Without a degree the multiplier will be only $600.00. When the Determine salary button is pressed, the script will display the extra paragraph element containing the calculated the salary offer as shown in the sample illustrations below.

I've tried everything I can possibly think of to try to make sure there is no alpha characters entered into the age field, but I can't seem to get it to work.  PLEASE HELP!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>


<head>
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset= utf-8' />
   <title>Form Based JavaScript</title>
   <style type = "text/css">
      h2 {text-align:left;}
      body {background-color:lightblue;}
      .input {font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;}
   </style>   

   <script type = "text/javascript">
      <!--
   function salary()  `enter code here`
      {
        var age;
        var degree;


      if (age != [0-99]
        {
            document.writeln( "The age that you entered must contain only numerals. <br /> Please re-enter it.");

      else if (age < 18)

           document.writeln( " Sorry - you must be 18 or older for this job. <br /> Please reapply in [18 - age] years." );


      else if (age >=18)

           document.writeln( " You qualify! Salary offer [degree * ] dollars. See our staff for an application" );
          }



      }


      // -->
   </script>

<!-- project6.htm Tatiana Saavedra 04/17/2013 -->

</head>

<body>

<h2> Applicant Screening Page </h2>

<hr />

<form id = "myForm" action = "">
   <p>Email:<input type = "email" id = "email"></p>
   <p>Age:<input type = "number" maxlength="3" size="3" id = "age"></p>
   <p><label>Check the box if you hold a college degree: <input type = "checkbox" id = "degree"></label></p>


<br />
<form action="">
 <input type="button" value="Determine Salary" onclick="salary()"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be declaring `age` and `degree` variables, but not assigning anything to them. That may be part of the problem.

Comment: Assign age with the `document.getElementById()` and go from there.

Comment: Don't use `document.write` from event handlers.

Comment: [`if age.match(/\D/) {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors opening and closing your brackets, check this before anything, your javascript is not loading and therefore not doing nothing, as the already told you, you're declaring the variables but not assigning them a value. I would also recommend you putting the javascript at the bottom of page

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
             function isInteger(n) 
             {
                if (n.indexOf('.') != -1)
                {
                   return false;//do not accept decimal numbers
                }
                return !isNaN(parseInt(n)) && isFinite(n);
             }
```

parseInt parses the value to integer, if the value contains alpha characters it returns NaN

isNaN checks if the result is NaN

isFinite handles the case where n starts with a number but contains caracters.

The reason you don't use only `isFinite` is because if you try `isFinite(' ')` it returns true.

Also make your comparaisons with the `parseInt(age)` value, its better since ur comparing numbers

Comment: Your explanation of [parseInt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) is incorrect, it only returns NaN if the string starts with something other than a digit or white space then a digit. Any other character is allowed after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
```

That is a really old DOCTYPE that should not be used (it was intended to assist the transition from HTML to XHTML more than 10 years ago, but that never happened). Just use:

```
<?DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset= utf-8' />
```

See? The content is HTML, being served as HTML. :-)
[...]

If this was XML, you just blanked the page. HTML comment delimiters haven't been necessary for nearly 20 years, they were never needed for script elements in the head in browsers conforming to an HTML standard. Don't use them.

```
function salary()  `enter code here`
  {
```

Oops, you can't have a string literal there. Put it in the function body. I like to put the opening brace on the same line as the function keyword and name. I'll assume the string sholdn't be there at all:

```
function salary() {
    var age;
    var degree;

    if (age != [0-99]
```

Missing a closing bracket ")".

```
    {
        document.writeln( "The age that you entered must contain only numerals. <br /> Please re-enter it.");
```

If you call `document.writeln` after the document has finsihed loading, it will first call `document.open`, which

clears all content from the document. What you probably want to do is add an element to the document and put the text inside it. Or put the text inside an element already in the page.

```
    else if (age < 18)
```

You should use braces around all if blocks, it makes the code easier to read. Sometimes it is convenient to omit them for very simple blocks and statements, but not here. S

```
       document.writeln( " Sorry - you must be 18 or older for this job. <br /> Please reapply in [18 - age] years." );
```

You seem to be trying to do arithmetic in a string, you can't do that. So replace `document.writeln` with writing to an element, and do the arithemtic like:

```
"Please reapply in " + (18 - age) + " years."
```

.

```
    else if (age >=18)
        document.writeln( " You qualify! Salary offer [degree * ] dollars. See our staff for an application" );
    }
  }
```

Same here.

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Applicant Screening Page </h2>
<hr>
<form id = "myForm" action = "">
    <p>Email:<input type = "email" id = "email"></p>
    <p>Age:<input type = "number" maxlength="3" size="3" id = "age"></p>
```

You can put an empty span after the age input to put messages into.

```
    <p><label>Check the box if you hold a college degree: <input type = "checkbox" id = "degree"></label></p>
```

Form controls need a name to be successful, they usually don't need an ID.

```
    <p>Email:<input type="email" name="email"></p>
    <p>Age:<input type ="number" maxlength="3" size="3" name="age"></p>
    <p><label>Check the box if you hold a college degree: <input type="checkbox" name="degree"></label></p>
    <br>
    <form action="">
```

You can't put a form in a form, just remove the above tag (it has no closing tag).

```
    <input type="button" value="Determine Salary" onclick="salary()">
```

You need a submit button to make the form submit.

```
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So have a go at updating your code and come back if you need more help.

Comment: <?DOCTYPE html> should be <!DOCTYPE html>